# Reading from file with ">>"

Tags: c++, file

I have the following persons file:

```
Name 0744112233 ASD
```

and the following piece of code

```
const string InFilePersonRepository::PFILE = "persons";

void InFilePersonRepository::load() {
        string delim = " ";
        string name, phone, address;
        ifstream fin(PFILE.c_str());
        while (fin.good()){
            fin>>name>>delim>>phone>>delim>>address;
            Person p(name,phone,address);
            persons.push_back(p);
        }
}
```

After the reading is done, the values of name, phone, address are: name = Name, phone = ASD,
address = "",

If the files has multiple lines, same problem, the second field in file is skipped. Why is that happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that

```
 void InFilePersonRepository::load() {
            string name, phone, address;
            ifstream fin(PFILE.c_str());
            while (fin.good()){
                fin>>name>>phone>>address;
                Person p(name,phone,address);
                persons.push_back(p);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but now i have an other problem, it adds the line twice. If there are 4 persons in file, the last one is added twice. There is no new line after the last row.

Comment: @VladC - That's because `while (fin.good())` stays true until the input has already failed once. Use `while(fin>>name>>phone>>address)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`>>` skips whitespace, so there is no need for `delim`. `fin >> name >> phone >> address` should do.

Comment: Thanks it works, but now i have an other problem, it adds the line twice. If there are 4 persons in file, the last one is added twice. There is no new line after the last row.

Comment: @VladC: After having read the last line, `fin.good()` will still be `true`. It is only after you attempt to actually read more that it will become `false`. I won't give you the entire solution since this looks like homework, but try to restructure the loop (hint: use `if` and `break`) so that you first try to read with `>>`, then check whether `fin.good()` still is `true`.